# Getting OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: error

Tags: docker, nginx

I'm trying to install the Concerto Computer Adaptive Testing platform on my Windows 10 Home machine, using the Docker Toolbox. The documentation for the installation is here:

https://github.com/campsych/concerto-platform/wiki/docker-compose-Installation-guide

However, at the final step on the docker PowerShell, I'm running into the following OCI error:

ERROR: for concerto  Cannot start service concerto: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "process_linux.go:402: container init caused \"rootfs_linux.go:58: mounting \\"/c/concerto/docker-compose/concerto/nginx/nginx.conf\\" to rootfs \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e973408c4164c862843c93d556ce3ca26f28945b64ef44f626d489011f78fb05/merged\\" at \\"/mnt/sda1/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e973408c4164c862843c93d556ce3ca26f28945b64ef44f626d489011f78fb05/merged/etc/nginx/nginx.conf\\" caused \\"not a directory\\"\"": unknown: Are you trying to mount a directory onto a file (or vice-versa)? Check if the specified host path exists and is the expected type

I have tried reinstalling everything, and made sure to add the appropriate PATH to my environmental variables, but it still does not work. Would anyone be able to help on this issue?